# Using Python to convert a string to an int. and only return a portion of the string

Tags: python, string, int

I'm very new to Python.  I want to use python to convert a string to and integer and return only a portion of the string.  I have the following string C000004N_37.  I want to convert and return just the 37 of the string.

Comment: Why 37? Why not 4? 4 is present in a portion of your string.

Comment: This is a good place to start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Will the integer you want to return always be preceded by "_"?

Comment: if the position of the string components is fixed, you use slicing, e.g. `n=int(s[-2:])` where s is `C000004N_37`

Comment: 37 is the reference marker for this route.  yes the int will always come after the _.  The route name is always C######@_the mile post.  the mile post could be 0-700

Comment: Route could be C000125S_23 for example

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you:

```
def get_route_marker(user_string):
    return int(user_string.split('_')[-1])
```

If all of your strings are in a list called 'list_of_strings':

```
route_markers = [get_route_marker(user_string) for user_string in list_of_strings]
```

Comment: It will work for that individual corridor's records..  But I have several hundred corridors.  I was trying to figure out so it would be like int(C######N_###.split('_')[-1])

Comment: I edited the code to work on any such formatted string.